# Angular 2: Loading dynamic component in innerHTML

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0

I have 2 @components say  and . Now, I have to load  dynamically as innerHTML in  say for e.g. as below

component-1.html

```
<div [innerHTML]="domEl | safeHtml"></div>
```

In the Angular2 component-1 class

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({  
  selector: 'component-1',

  templateUrl: './component-1.html',

  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit {    

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.domEl = '<component-2 data="1234"></component-2>'
  }
}
```

component-2 is already inject in app.module.ts file via declarations[]. Also safeHtml is the pipes used for safe HTML transformation.

Even then the problem is component-2 is not loading. Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Note:

- if I include component-2 in component-1.html directly it will work. But we have a case where we cannot inject component-2 dynamically.
- Stack is build on Angular2, TypeScript and Webpack.

Comment: Instead of loading innerHtml, use templates with ngIf or ngSwitch.

Comment: Cannot do that, In my case that will not work.

Comment: You can't inject component as html. Components are rendered from Shadow Dom to Real Dom. When you inject something using **innerHTML**, It's expected to be raw Html, not stuff thats need rendering pipeline. As I said before, you must use ngIf or ngSwitch

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't process HTML passed to `[innerHTML]="..."` except sanitization for security purposes. Bindings, components, directives, ... are not created, because as mentioned, Angular ignores the content. What you can do is to create a component at runtime like explained in [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960). AFAIR someone built a module that makes this easier but I don't remember details.